# How to detect suspicious location changes?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an iOs app that tracks the user’s location and then downloads data with those information.

Whenever the user moves, it calls my site, saves the user’s location in the database, and returns some values.

**fetchData.php**

```
// update user.location user.locationTime in the database
// return some values
```

But I don’t wanna people to fool my app with fake locations. I know, there’s no way to prevent that from happening 100%, but at least do something about it.

Is there some kind of way to check if location changes between the already saved one and the new one is suspicious?

For example:

If user is in England xy street at 10:00 and the next location is 10:05 but America then it might be fake..

Like user is allowed to change locations maximum 20m/s

But allow user to travel with planes also but max 1 times per day  (higher travel speed).

Comment: You simply need to check that within the last updated geo point you received and the new one, would they realistically be able to travel in that time. Now, this can become complicated if you don't know if the users mode of transport.

Comment: What if I have a connecting flight with a 3 hour layover?

Comment: 20m/s is 72km/h if I'm correct

Comment: Yeah that’s the problem.. I wrote the thread in hope there’s a known solution for this, but if not well yeah.. I don’t know. Maybe determine the max speed travelling value (for example 2000km/h)?